# Unable to reuse SASS @mixin: Previous parameter value being used again

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I have 3x circle icons (based on font-awesome icons) and I am trying to add a glow effect using sass @mixin.

_mixins.scss

```
@mixin textGlow($glowColor: 0){
    @keyframes glow{
        from {
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px $glowColor, 0 0 2px $glowColor, 0 0 3px $glowColor;
        }
        to {
            text-shadow: 0 0 3px lighten($glowColor, 5%), 0 0 4px lighten($glowColor, 15%), 0 0 5px lighten($glowColor, 30%);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes glow{
        from {
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px $glowColor, 0 0 2px $glowColor, 0 0 3px $glowColor;
        }
        to {
            text-shadow: 0 0 3px lighten($glowColor, 5%), 0 0 4px lighten($glowColor, 15%), 0 0 5px lighten($glowColor, 30%);
        }
    }

    -webkit-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

app.component.scss

```
@import '../styles/variables';
@import '../styles/mixins';

i.fa-circle.good{
  color: $my-green;
  @include textGlow($my-green);
}

i.fa-circle.bad{
  color: $my-red;
  @include textGlow($my-red);
}
```

_variables.scss

```
$my-green: #00BB9C;
$my-red: #FB4D62;
```

However, as you can see, there's a red glow around the green icons even though I have passed in `$my-red` for `.bad` class.

[image: error sample picture]

**The last color parameter passed in to the @mixin will always cause all the glows to have that same last colour.**

I have read a few tutorials on @mixin so far to try and figure out if I have used @mixin incorrectly, but I couldn't figure out my mistake. I have tried re-assigning to a local $local-colour variable in the mixin but to no avail.

Isn't the purpose of mixin to allow a bunch of css properties to be reused? Could someone please point out how am I using @mixin wrongly? Or if I shouldn't even be using @mixin in this situation?

I have recreated a **[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-4tvs1d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the keyframe name that you are using. The following change should help you.

mixins.scss

```
@mixin textGlow($name, $glowColor){
    @keyframes #{$name}{
        from {
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px $glowColor, 0 0 2px $glowColor, 0 0 3px $glowColor;
        }
        to {
            text-shadow: 0 0 3px lighten($glowColor, 5%), 0 0 4px lighten($glowColor, 15%), 0 0 5px lighten($glowColor, 30%);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name}{
        from {
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px $glowColor, 0 0 2px $glowColor, 0 0 3px $glowColor;
        }
        to {
            text-shadow: 0 0 3px lighten($glowColor, 5%), 0 0 4px lighten($glowColor, 15%), 0 0 5px lighten($glowColor, 30%);
        }
    }

    -webkit-animation: $name 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: $name 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: $name 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

app.component.scss

```
i.fa-circle.good{
  color: $my-green;
  @include textGlow('greenglow', $my-green);
}

i.fa-circle.bad{
  color: $my-red;
  @include textGlow('redglow', $my-red);
}
```

[image]